# unable to find the class in namespace in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Ui folder path=> resources\views\DistributorRegitration.php

```
< ?php

namespace resources\views;

    class DistributorRegitrationForm
    {

        public  function distributorRegitrationFormHtml(){

            return  'hello'
    }

    }
```

Controller folder path => App\Http\Controllers\DistributorRegistration.php

```
< ?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use resources\views\DistributorRegitrationForm;


class DistributorRegistration  extends Controller

{ 

public function VestigePOS_DistributorRegistration()

{

$distribtutor_reg_form_obj = new DistributorRegitrationForm(); //class in DistributorRegistration.php            
$returned_dist_reg_html = $distribtutor_reg_form_obj->distributorRegitrationFormHtml(); // Function in DistributorRegistrationForm class.

return view($returned_dist_reg_html) ;      
}

}

?>
```

when i called this controller 
Fatal error: Class 'resources\views\DistributorRegitrationForm' not found
[image]

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: have you created the mentioned view

Comment: cahek the screen shot updated

Comment: i want to return a function from UI in to controller

Comment: method injection from Ui

Comment: i'm  unable to solve for a week..

Answer (score 0):

Rename `resources\views\DistributorRegitration.php` to the `resources\views\DistributorRegitrationForm.php`

Comment: try to add the class to the autoloader.

Comment: how to add class in autoloader ? please explain

Comment: update the composer.json "autoload" section: "classmap": [
            "database"`, "resources/views"`
        ] and run from terminal `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the file or directory in the autoload classmap section in composer.json in order for the class to be autoloaded.

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "resources/views/"
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the view `DistributorRegitration.blade.php` and move the class inside it in a new file in `app` folder, for example with name `DistributorRegitrationFormClass.php`.

Then in the controller change this line:

```
use resources\views\DistributorRegitrationForm;
```

to

```
use App\DistributorRegitrationForm;
```

and the return view statement to

```
return view('DistributorRegitration', ['returned_dist_reg_html' => $returned_dist_reg_html]);
```

In the view write `{{returned_dist_reg_html}}` and magically 'hello' will appear.